# Titles have [ closed ] appended incorrectly when a close vote is cast from the 10k tools

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, 10k-tools

If I mark a question as an exact duplicate in the 10k tools flag page, the question title will have `[closed]` appended even if my vote wasn't enough to close the question.

[image]

Comment: k; will investigate

Comment: this should be fixed next deploy

Comment: Sorry for the weird title edit... I was trying to remove the escape backslashes because they don't work in titles. The result almost motivated me to post a "Titles that contain but do not end with the closed indicator should not be rejected" feature request, but I decided that this is such an edge case that it wouldn't be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>don't bump me mister community</sub>

This was a side effect of my streamlining of the "close" voting in `/review`

Comment: community will bump no more.