# Is the closed indicator in the title preventing access to a question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, title

The first result of [the MSO search results for `user:131713 closed`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A131713+closed) is "Reject user-entered titles that end with the string '[closed]'" (question ID 70729). When I try to view that question, I get the error message

> ### The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

I suspect that the presence of "[closed]" in the title has something to do with this error. In fact, the reason I was looking for that question in the first place had to do with me being unable to edit [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112072/131713)'s title to contain "[closed]."

Comment: Yeah, it keeps redirecting to itself. If you [manually fix the slug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70729/reject-user-entered-titles-that-end-with-the-string-closed), you can view it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I edited this question so it doesn't experience the redirect loop (that shouldn't be able to happen in the future, because of the new "[closed]" restriction).

Answer (score 2):

Repro'd in chrome.  The request returns a 301 redirect to the same URL.

[image]

([clicky here for bigger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqcH1.png))