# Titles have [on hold] appended incorrectly when a close vote is cast from the 10k tools

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, 10k-tools

If I VtC a question in the 10k tools flag page, the question title will have `[on hold]` appended even if my vote wasn't enough to close the question.

> [image]

<sup>This seems to be a regression of [Titles have [ closed ] appended incorrectly when a close vote is cast from the 10k tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112072/titles-have-closed-appended-incorrectly-when-a-close-vote-is-cast-from-the-1)</sup>

Comment: This question should be put [on hold] until that [on-hold] in the title is fixed.

Comment: @cole: I dare you to try (`[on hold]` is blocked from titles!)

Comment: Matt, I dared. Sorry, but it seems it can be done. Or is it only on the question's end?

Comment: @Mołot: Is that using some space-which-isn't-a-space magic, or is there a [meta-tag:bug] in that the `[on hold]` check only takes place on the initial post, and not successive edits? :P

Comment: @Matt it's non-breakable space - the one that makes most sense there for me.

Comment: Confirmed - just observed this behavior today.  Was all set to post a bug about it with pictures and everything...