# "These words are not allowed in titles"... But is there anyway...?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, title, quality-filter

I went to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778373/i-need-help-with-lp-using-cplex-python) and noticed this...

[image]

Bearing in mind this was pre-edit - how did the question successfully post in the first place?

To clarify, [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21778373/2) of this post has this:

[image]

Revision #3 is when I then edited that out...

So I guess the question is, **how did revision 2 successfully submit** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've adjusted our test to disallow any type of space between "help" and "with", on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks! While you're at it, can you do the same for "`[on hold]`" too?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - looking into that. It is a completely different check done in a completely different place, in a completely different way ;)

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

it is easy:

> I Need help#with....

Replace the hash with Alt+255. which is a space, but not a space. So for the filter it is one word " help#with ". So it passes the filter, try it out. I have made an edit for the same question in SO, if someone can accept it so it will show, my rep there is not enough to edit it myself.

**List of Unicode letters that can fool the filter:**

```
U+00A0
U+202F
U+FEFF
```

There could be more..

Comment: No. @JonClements got that error while editing. Go to the question and try to edit that keyword.

Comment: @hims056 updated the answer.

Comment: The filter does take zero-width and other non-standard spaces into account, actually. And the output doesn't contain that character either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have tried it and it worked :) should I post a question in SO just to prove that?

Comment: @MeNoTalk: Sure, it could easily be that I missed one. I don't use  Windows; do you know what Unicode codepoint Alt+255 produces?

Comment: Ah, found it, U+00A0, confirmed that.

Comment: That may well work, but it doesn't seem to be how the OP did it; the title doesn't have any non-ASCII code points.

Comment: it is U+00A0 I guess

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I tried it, the non-breaking space is filtered out.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: see http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21778373/12; that revision uses the U+00A0 character.

Comment: FWIW: Please see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209734/187824).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OK, that's just weird. I just downloaded the page and looked at it in a hex editor, and all the spaces are normal ones! It's as if the back-end is normalizing them, but only *after* the word blacklist check.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: exactly.

Comment: They are being normalized after they pass the filter...

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sounds like time for a bug report, then.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: this very question can be that bug report.